# I need help ordering nested loops by integers and displaying them

Tags: python, list, nested, integer

I need help ordering a nested list by a specific integer in it, first I sorted the order of numbers in each list, eg `[['Bob',[3,2,1]],['Kate',[5,4,3]]]`.

But now I need to order each object(list) in the list according to the first number of each object from highest to lowest, for example: `[['Bob',[3,2,1]],

I then need to print out the highest number in each list of numbers with the name.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using nested lists?  A dictionary would seem a much better fit for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> sorted( [['Bob',[3,2,1]],['Kate',[5,4,3]],['Jim',[4,3,2]]], key=lambda l:-l[1][0])
[['Kate', [5, 4, 3]], ['Jim', [4, 3, 2]], ['Bob', [3, 2, 1]]]
```

Then to print as you describe:

```
>>> li=[['Bob',[3,2,1]],['Kate',[5,4,3]],['Jim',[4,3,2]]]
>>> ["{}: {}".format(n, max(sl)) for n, sl in sorted(li, key=lambda l:l[1][0], reverse=True)]
['Kate: 5', 'Jim: 4', 'Bob: 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look up the sort function in python and the key parameter.

```
myList = [['Bob',[3,2,1]],['Kate',[5,4,3]],['Jim',[4,3,2]]]
myList.sort(key= lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print myList 

[['Kate', [5, 4, 3]], ['Jim', [4, 3, 2]], ['Bob', [3, 2, 1]]]
```

Comment: i would go with `x[1][0]`, as the op mentions the first number

Comment: I'm assuming that in the event of a tie, the second best score should be used, rather than just preserving the initial ordering of the list.  If my assumption is correct, then the x[1] is better

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible:

```
data = [['Bob',[3,2,1]],['Kate',[5,4,3]],['Jim',[4,3,2]]] 

print sorted(data,key=lambda x: x[0][1])
```

here x[0][1] points to the value on which you want to have it sorted, in this case the first number of the array. This is assuming that the array of numbers is already sorted.
The code prints:

```
[['Kate', [5, 4, 3]], ['Jim', [4, 3, 2]], ['Bob', [3, 2, 1]]]
```